# Why are hash values being printed twice

Tags: linux, perl

## Problem

Hash values are printed twice in for(each) loop.

---

## Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %Hash;

my $x=1;

foreach my $item( 1..9 ) {
   $Hash{$x} = $x;
   print scalar keys %Hash,",$item,",$x++,"\n"
}
$x=1;
foreach my $iteml( %Hash){
        print $x++,"\n";
        print "||||$iteml------$Hash{$iteml}||||\n";
}

print "@{[%Hash]}\n";
```

---

## Output

```
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3
4,4,4
5,5,5
6,6,6
7,7,7
8,8,8
9,9,9
1
||||6------6||||
2
||||6------6||||
3
||||3------3||||
4
||||3------3||||
5
||||7------7||||
6
||||7------7||||
7
||||9------9||||
8
||||9------9||||
9
||||2------2||||
10
||||2------2||||
11
||||8------8||||
12
||||8------8||||
13
||||1------1||||
14
||||1------1||||
15
||||4------4||||
16
||||4------4||||
17
||||5------5||||
18
||||5------5||||
6 6 3 3 7 7 9 9 2 2 8 8 1 1 4 4 5 5
```

---

## Question

Why is this happening?

---

## Version

```
v5.10.0 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For one, you iterate over *the hash* itself, `(%Hash)`.  So you are getting keys and values, the list.

What makes it interesting is that the hash has the same keys and values. So it prints the key and its value, which is the same. Then it prints the value, and then uses it as the key ... which is a valid key, and with the same value.  So it looks like it prints it twice :)